# How to reload the webpage when orientation changes?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, media-queries

I'm trying to trigger an event with jQuery mobile that automatically reloads the page when the device's orientation changes. I have media queries written with `max-device-width,` `orientation:landscape,` and `orientation: portrait`. Since the `<video>` wont scale properly...the only solution I can think of is to refresh the page to the correct media query with the device is rotated.

How do I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the `onorientationchange` event?

Comment: @oomlaut A little bit.

Comment: @Ross It didn't work. Just paste your code in the <script> tag in the <head> with jQuery mobile linked correct? Is this kind of event even possible?

Comment: @DavidBerning Did you check to see if the `orientationchange` event fires?  Put an `alert` or `console.log` in it to see if it triggers.  What version of jQM are you using?  You can try `$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e) {} );` instead of using `on`.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks guys who answered but I found this and used this and it worked perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // RELOADS WEBPAGE WHEN MOBILE ORIENTATION CHANGES  
    window.onorientationchange = function() { 
        var orientation = window.orientation; 
            switch(orientation) { 
                case 0:
                case 90:
                case -90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; } 
    };
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.  One suggestion - You don't need the switch statement.  Like this instead - `window.onorientationchange = function() { 
 window.location.reload();
};`

Comment: @Ross I'll try that tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {
     $.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
});
```

It would be best to namespace that orientationchange event to a specific page.

[jQM docs on orientationchange event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code to redirect the page on orientation event, its work well for me

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() { location.reload(); }, false);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (event) {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: This one is simple as that.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        console.log(screen.orientation);
}, false);
</script>
```